# How to get untransformed position in vertex shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am applying a transform to my model using:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glMultTransposeMatrixd(transform, 0);
```

Here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 110

varying vec4 pos;
varying vec3 N;
varying vec4 vertColor;

void main(void)  
{    
    gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    pos = gl_Vertex;
    N = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
    vertColor = gl_Color;
}
```

How can I get the position without the model matrix applied to it?  That is, as if I did not apply `glMultTransposeMatrixd(transform, 0)` in the first place.

I've tried `gl_Vertex * gl_ModelViewMatrixInverse` -- I'm not sure if this is a valid thing to do -- but it did not give anything like the right result.

Comment: Anyhow, think about moving to modern OpenGL, where you don't have any of those predefined matrices, and the vertex shader gets the vertex attributes (including the positions) just as you pass them to the GL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't undo a matrix multiplication without the inverse of that matrix. Since your transformation matrix has been combined with the camera matrix, `gl_ModelViewMatrixInverse` is not the inverse of `transform`. As others have mentioned, the best way to get the untransformed position is simply to not do the transformation at all.

Just pass `transform` to the shader as a uniform, and then apply it as needed. In fact, modern OpenGL does away with the built in matrices all together and requires you to pass your own matrices exclusively using uniforms.

Also, you might consider consolidating the camera and projection transforms into one matrix and using a second for model transforms. Then, applying just the model transform matrix gets you the world position and applying both gets you the screen position.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the coordinates before/without applying a transformation to it, just don't apply a transformation to it. The untransformed vertex data is just `gl_Vertex` in your case.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained further: I need **both** the position transformed and untransformed.

Comment: You can use both. In your code, `gl_Vertex` is the untransformed, and `gl_Position` the transformed one.